# How did 'purchase' evolve to mean 'firm contact or grip'?

Tags: etymology

> [1] [purchase](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purchase) =  2. [mass noun] Firm contact or grip

I've been trying to understand how the noun **purchase** evolved to mean definition 2 above. I heed the Etymological Fallacy. I tried [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154831?rskey=2XyXXF&result=1&isAdvanced=false) but it's too terse and jumbled; so I turned to:

> [2] [Etymonline for **purchase (n.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=purchase&allowed_in_frame=0) : ... The sense of "hold or position for advantageously applying power" (1711) is extended from the nautical verb meaning "to haul or draw (especially by mechanical power)," often used in reference to hauling up anchors, attested from 1560s. ...

In view of this reference to a nautical definition, I returned to ODO and encountered:

> [3] [purchase](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purchase) = {verb} 2. {Nautical} `Haul` up (a rope, cable, or anchor) by means of a pulley or lever.

I still couldn't perceive the etymology; so I tried to consider the morphemes:

> [4] [Etymonline for **purchase (v.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=purchase&allowed_in_frame=0) : ... from *pur*- "***forth***" (possibly used here as an intensive prefix; see [pur-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pur-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + Old French *chacier* "run after, to hunt, ***chase***" (see [chase](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chase&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). . ...

My confusion worsened. How does [3] relate to [4]? In other words, how can a ***chase*** ***forth*** possibly mean a `haul`? Any object to be hauled is tied by a cable; so what's there to ***chase***?

Comment: When you haul up an anchor rope, you're chasing for the end of the rope where the anchor is attached.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be as in when you purchase goods, you are bringing them to you.  Thus when you pull on the rope, you are bringing the anchor to you.  The idea of drawing near makes the meaning similar?

Perhaps the idea of "gripping" something was taken from gripping the rope rather than just pulling the anchor towards you?

I also agree with the other person who said, "chasing the anchor end of the rope".